# $f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}x$; $g(x)=x(1-x^2)$; show $g\circ f$ continuous at 0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

> If $f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}x$ and $g(x)=x(1-x^2)$, then show that their composition $g\circ f$ is continuous at 0.

How to determine whether such composition $g\circ f$ is continuous? Please solve this problem. What about the continuity of $f\circ g$ then?

Comment: do you mean $$g\circ f =sgn(x)(1-sgn(x)^2)$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes. It is......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h(x)= g \circ f = \mbox{sgn}(x)(1−\mbox{sgn}^2(x))$. For $x>0$, $\mbox{sgn}(x)=1$ so $h(x) = 0$. For $x=0$, $\mbox{sgn}(x)=0$ so $h(x) = 0$. For $x<0$, $\mbox{sgn}(x)=-1$ so $h(x) = 0$. Thus $h(x)$ is a constant function, and therefore is continuous.

On the other hand, the function $k(x)= f \circ g = \mbox{sgn} \left( x(1-x^2) \right)$ is discontinuous at $x = \pm 1$.